# EventAggregator in Prism between ViewModels

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to make a sample with eventAggregator and latest Prism v7.
The sample is built with the Prism template pack, a page with a button that loads another page, in the button I Publish an event and in the constructor of the second page i Subscribe it, then write on a label if the event has been received.

First Page:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms and Prism!" />
        <Button Command="{Binding Button1Command}" Text="ContentPage1" />
</StackLayout>
```

Second page:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Message}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
```

First viewmodel:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {    
        IEventAggregator _ea;

        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) 
            : base (navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Main Page";    
            _ea = eventAggregator;
        }

        public DelegateCommand<string> Button1Command => new DelegateCommand<string>(Button1Navigate);

        private async void Button1Navigate(string par)
        {           
            _ea.GetEvent<BasicEvent>().Publish("basicEvent");
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("PrismContentPage1");    
        }        
    }
```

Second ViewModel:

```
public class PrismContentPage1ViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        IEventAggregator _ea;

        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
        }

        public PrismContentPage1ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
            _ea = eventAggregator;    
            _ea.GetEvent<BasicEvent>().Subscribe(OnInitializationEventFired);
        }

        public void OnInitializationEventFired(string message)
        {
            Message = "received";
        }
    }
```

The label never gets the "received" string.
I stripped the code of many other tests: I've added a button in second page to Publish from inside the same ViewModel, and then works.
I debugged and inspected the eventAggregator, and if when is initialized in the second page it actually has 1 item, the BasicEvent.

The first time I run it, it doesn't fire the event, then I go back to first page (I know, without unsubscribing), and press the button again, and this second time it gets fired, but yet, Message is not changed in the label.

It seems all very simple, and samples (HamburgerMenu, UsingEventAggregator) work, but not this very basic sample I'm doing, can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll receive the events published *after* you have subscribed to the event. All events fired before are lost to you, because you cannot subscribe retroactively.

Comment: Oh I got it! I thought that the eventAggregator was also working in a way that when an event gets published it lives in the eventAggregator stack until a Subscriber gets instantiated, and then the event is delivered.
Isn't there anything like this?

Comment: Nothing built into prism, as far as I know, but you can replace the standard 'EventAggregator' with a `StoringEventAggregator`, if you write one.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues:

1. "PrismContentPage1ViewModel" is not created before you navigate to there. Try to add breakpoint on "_ea.GetEvent

   You want to pass some values to next viewmodel? If yes, you are doing it wrong. Use [NavigationParameters](http://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/Navigation-Service.html#passing-parameters).

Bonus: don't use hardcoded view strings like "PrismContentPage1". If you can write [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof). It will help later if you change view name and navigation does not work anymore because you forgot to change view name in navigation

Comment: 1. I'm following the Prism samples, and I can't see any explicit creation of the ViewModels, I guess the NavigationService takes care of that. Also, I debugged it and it always passes from _ea.GetEvent.Subscribe
2. Yes I know this is just a sample to make eventAggregator work

Comment: You are right, NavigationService takes care of that. You basically register view and related viewmodel somewhere. Navigating to view via reflection creates viewmodel and injects all services what is in constructor. Or at least it is how I understand what is under the hood after working half year with Prism framework.                                     
Opened now UsingEventAggregator example and there isn't anything like in you example that you send publish event and after that navigate to that view. If you swap these 2 lines it works ok?

Comment: If I press the Button in the first page, an event gets published and then I navigate to the second page where I subscribe to the same event, but it doesn't fire.
If I publish and subscribe into the same viewmodel (as a test) it fires.
In the UsingEventAggregator it does more or less this, publishing an event and navigateing to another page where it subscribes and there it works.

Comment: Because it subscribes before sending. Just add breakpoints and check what first is in example: subscribing or publishing of event. I could not able to launch their example yesterday